# geopandas spatial join with conditions / additional columns

Tags: pandas, geospatial, spatial, geopandas

I have two DataFrames with `Lat`, `Long` columns and other additional columns. For example,

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
                    'id': [0, 1, 2],
                    'dt': [01-01-2022, 02-01-2022, 03-01-2022],
                    'Lat': [33.155480, 33.155480, 33.155480],
                    'Long': [-96.731630, -96.731630, -96.731630]
                  })


df2 = pd.DataFrame({
                    'val': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
                    'dt': [01-01-2022, 02-01-2022, 03-01-2022],
                    'Lat': [33.155480, 33.155480, 33.155480],
                    'Long': [-96.731630, -96.731630, -96.731630]
                  })
```

I'd like to do a spatial join not just on `lat`, `long` but also on date column. Expected output:

```
id   dt           lat         long         val

0    01-01-2022   33.155480   -96.731630   a
1    02-01-2022   33.155480   -96.731630   b
2    03-01-2022   33.155480   -96.731630   c
```

Comment: Are the lat/lons identical? If so, you could perform the join using pandas (not geopandas) with pd.merge

Comment: @MichaelDelgado No, they are not always identical. I think i need `sjoin_nearest`

Comment: If they’re really close (e.g. it’s an exact join to a tolerance) you could round first and then use pd.merge. Unfortunately there is no option currently to do a spatial join with other columns as well using geopandas and you’ll have to resort to using an outer loop to subset the data for each date.